# TinyMce4 Expire Date

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

We use tinymce4 in our company. If we don't switch to tinymce5, will we no longer be able to use the editor after February 25, 2021? thanks to helpers
https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-migrate-from-tinymce-4-to-tinymce-5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDN will be switched off on February 25, 2021.

This will impact your project only if you rely on TinyMCE CDN to include TinyMCE in your project (https://cdn.tinymce.com/, https://cloud.tinymce.cloud/ or https://cdn.tiny.cloud/)

You can still continue to use TinyMCE by hosting it yourself on your server or by using a third party CDN (for instance: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tinymce/4.9.11)

End of support for TinyMCE 4 is December 31, 2020. This means no new version of TinyMCE 4 will be released after this date.