# Unable to modify 2sxc content

Tags: 2sxc

I am unable to modify the 2sxc component texts due the follow error “Your access to TinyMCE will expire on 25 Februrary 2021. Please either contact your administrator or upgrade your account using the instructions available here.”
Atteched there are the image of error and the version of 2sxc installed (8.7.0).

[error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8fHN.png)

[2sxc version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhaAc.png)

Answer (score 1):

The recipe (Azing) to fix this is here.
https://azing.org/2sxc/r/Ay7TYQxx

Other references

https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2269 < details, solution

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/2sic/2sxc/2269/758134847

[TinyMce4 Expire Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855391/tinymce4-expire-date)